# Django migrations not applied to the connected database

Tags: python, mysql, django

So i'm working on adapting an existing django (v1.11.5) project and I migrated my modifications:

```
$ python2 manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'genetics_ark':
  genetics_ark/migrations/0002_analysis_analysisvariant_annotation_cnv_decon_deconcnv_decongene_decongenecnv_deconsample_gene_genep.py
    - Create model Analysis
    - Create model AnalysisVariant
    - Create model Annotation
    - Create model Gene
    - Create model GenePanel
    - Create model Meta
    - Create model Model
    - Create model ModelRegion
    - Create model Panel
    - Create model Reference
    - Create model Region
    - Create model SamplePanel
    - Create model Transcript
    - Create model TranscriptRegion
    - Create model CNV
    - Create model Decon
    - Create model DeconCNV
    - Create model Decongene
    - Create model DecongeneCNV
    - Create model DeconSample

$ python2 manage.py migrate
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
        HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'genetics_ark_db'
        HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, genetics_ark, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying genetics_ark.0001_initial... OK
  Applying genetics_ark.0002_analysis_analysisvariant_annotation_cnv_decon_deconcnv_decongene_decongenecnv_deconsample_gene_genep... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

However, the models I added were not added to the database while the django parts were i.e. :

- auth_group
- auth_group_permissions
- auth_permission
- auth_user
- auth_user_groups
- auth_user_user_permissions
- django_admin_log
- django_content_type
- django_migrations
- django_session

I already modified the database using a previous version of the project and i couldn't find any difference that could explain why it doesn't work. Additionally, when i "runserver", it doesn't work and no error message is displayed in the terminal.
Any advice?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble you could simply delete the _migrations_ folder and delete and re-create the database in Postgres, then `python2 manage.py makemigrations [app]` and `python2 manage.py migrate`. This way you get a clean setup again.

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
python2 manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

Django doesnot detect changes in migration in initial phase.. so you have to specify app name for the first time.. thereafter you could simply do

```py
python2 manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Also, there was already a initial phase since i cloned the project from our gitlab.

Comment: is there a migrations folder inside your project?? if not try creating one and create a __init__.py inside it and try migrating again.

Comment: There is and the migrations files are there with the modifications I made to the models

Answer (score 0):

you can silence individual checks in your settings. For example, if you determine django_mysql.W002 doesn’t require your attention, add the following to settings.py:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = [
    'django_mysql.W002',
]
```

you can see this [document](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks.html)